# How to concatenate records based on a GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a structure like:

```
| id | textfield | text_group | 
| 1  | yes       | 123        | 
| 2  | y         | 123        | 
| 3  | no        | abc        | 
| 4  | n         | abc        |
```

I'd like to return all records, but such that I get:

```
| colA  | text_group | 
| yes y | 123        |
| no n  | abc        |
```

Is this possible simply with a query, or will I need to use some programming to format it as such?  I would have done a group by, but then I lose the information in result ColA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function should do the trick:

```
SELECT   group_concat (textfield SEPARATOR ' ') AS colA, text_group
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY text_group
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) :

```
SELECT text_group
     , GROUP_CONCAT(textfield SEPARATOR ' ') AS colA
FROM table
GROUP BY text_group
```

Comment: _with_ the appropriate `GROUP BY text_group`

Comment: if the group concat is gonna be very large dont forget to 
SET group_concat_max_len=100000000